# Edit Multiple Cells on DataGrid then Save to database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagrid

I want to edit multiple cells in DataGrid, and when btnUpdate is clicked the cells I edited will be updated in database.

[image]

I have tried the ff code for btnUpdate:

```
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to apply changes?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgMain.SelectedRows)
            {
                DataTable d = dgMain.DataSource as DataTable;
                long attendanceid = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells["Attendance_Id"].Value.ToString());
                EmployeeAttendance a = new EmployeeAttendance();
                a.ProcAccountingAttendance_Update(attendanceid);
            }               
            MessageBox.Show("Changes Successfully Saved!");
        }
```

**But the problem is it still doesnt Update the database.**

Comment: i do not see any linkage between your data table and update method call..what your update method doing actually ?

Comment: If you use a DataAdapter to load the datatable used to fill the grid you just need to pass the DataTable to its Update method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I have finally solved the problem with the ff code:
BTW, I am using a stored procedure for my database

```
private void dgMain_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = dgMain.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Attendance_Id"].Value.ToString();
        string columnname = dgMain.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        string value = dgMain.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        EmployeeAttendance a = new EmployeeAttendance();
        a.ProcAccountingAttendance_UpdateByGroupIdDateFromTo(Convert.ToInt64(id),columnname,value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem is you are going through `selectedRows` only which means if you changed multiple values and after all that you select only one row, only that one will be updated.

Next problem is that you are going through all selected rows, the ones with change and ones without it.

What I would do in your place is this:

- Create public class like this:

class:

```
public class ChangedData
{
    public Object primaryKey;
    public Object columnName;
    public Object columnValue;
}
```

- Create `public List<ChangedData> changedData;` inside your form
- Call `cellValidating` event and inside it check if old and new values are different, if they are different then do `changedData.Add(new ChangedData { primaryKey = primaryKeyOfYourTable, columnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name, columnValue.FormattedValue });`
- And finally when you press update button you go

this:

```
using(SqlConnection con...)
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE YOURTABLE SET @ColumnName =  @ColumnValue where PrimaryKeyColumn = @PrimaryKey", con);
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnValue");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryKey");

        foreach(ChangedData cd in changedData)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = cd.columnName.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters["@ColumnValue"].Value = cd.columnValue.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters["@PrimaryKey"].Value = cd.primaryKey.ToString();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Code I wrote is not tested and need editing since you haven't provided us with any code you have or structure of your database. If you need something else edit answer or comment.